# Fast algorithm to find out the number of points under hyperplane

Tags: algorithm, geometry, partitioning, space

Given points in Euclidean space, is there a fast algorithm to count the number of points 'under' one arbitrary hyperplane? Fast means time complexity lower than O(n)

Time for preprocessing or sorting the points is okay

And, even if not high dimensional, I'd like to know whether  there exists one that can be used in 2 dimension space

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to preprocess the points, then you have to visit each one at least once, which is O(n).  If you consider a test of which side the point is on as part of the preprocessing then you've got an O(0) algorithm (with O(n) preprocessing).  So I don't think this question makes sense as stated.

Nevertheless, I'll attempt to give a useful answer, even if it's not precisely what the OP asked for.

Choose a hyperplane unit normal and root point.  If the plane is given in parametric form

> **(P - O).N == 0**

then you have these already, just make sure the normal is unitized.

If it's given in analytic form: Sum(i = 1 to n: a[i] x[i]) + d = 0, then the vector A = (a[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), ... a[n]) is a normal of the plane, and N = A/||A|| is the unit plane normal.  A point O (for origin) on the plane is d N.

You can test which side each point P is on by projecting it onto N add checking the sign of the parameter:

Let V = P - O.  V is the vector from the chosen origin O to P.

Let s N be the [projection of V onto N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).  If s is negative, then P is "under" the hyperplane.

You should go to the link on vector projection if you're rusty on the subject, but I'll summarize here using my notation.  Or, you can take my word for it, and just skip to the formula at the end.

If alpha is the angle between V and N, then from the definition of cosine we have cos(alpha) = s||N||/||V|| = s/||V|| since N is a unit normal.  But we also know from vector algebra that cos(alpha) = ||V||(V.N), where "." is scalar product (a.k.a. dot product, or euclidean inner product).

Equating these two expressions for cos(alpha) we have

> **s = (V.V)(V.N)**

(using the fact that ||V||^2 == V.V).

So your proprocesing work is to compute N and O, and your test is:

```
bool is_under = (dot(V, V)*dot(V, N) < 0.);
```

I don't believe it can be done any faster.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the point values, use checking conditions at that point setting. Then increment or dont increment the counter. O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I found O(logN) algorithm in 2D dimension by using divide-and-conquer and binary search with O(N log N) preprocessing time complexity and O(N log N) memory complexity

The basic idea is that points can be divided into left N/2 points and right N/2 points, and the number of points that's under the line(in 2D dimension) is sum of the number of left points under the line and the number of the right points under the line. I'll call the infinite line that divides whole points into 'left' and 'right' as 'dividing line'. Dividing line will be look like 'x = k'

If each 'left points' and 'right points' are sorted by y-axis order, then the number of specific points - the points at the right lower corner - can be quickly found by using binary searching 'the number of points whose y values are lower than the y value of intersection point of the line and the Dividing line'.

Therefore time complexity is

T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(log N)

and finally the time complexity is O(log N)

Comment: @DeepYellow if the points are sorted by x order, then dividing left N/2 points and right N/2 points takes O(1) order.

Comment: Oh.. T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(log N) means T(N) = O(N), not O(log N).. I  should find another way.